# Observed Matplotlib animation duration doubled compared to theory

Tags: python, numpy, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot an animated sine signal as if it's passing through a figure window. So I expect that it takes 5 seconds for a 3-sec sine signal to pass through a 2-second window in my animation.

However, looking at the pop-up figure live, it takes twice as long by clock time on my machine using the following code, adapted from this excellent tutorial: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/ .

The recorded video seems OK at the specified frame rate though.

I can't seem to see where I did wrong in the logic. Is it just a performance issue? If so, how should I optimize the code with constraints, e.g., if possible, I hope I won't have to lower the sampling rate? The purpose of this is to prepare for drawing real-time data coming from the network.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import sys

# Signal comes in from right to left.

SR = 44100  # sampling rate in Hz
DurSec = 3  # Signal duration in seconds
Freq = 440  # frequency in Hz
Amp = 1.0   # amplitude
WindowDurSec = 2  # figure window size in seconds

FPS = 30    # frame per second
msPerSec = 1000
frameDurMs = int(np.floor(1 / FPS * msPerSec))  # animation frame duration
passThruSec = WindowDurSec + DurSec  # Playback stops at DurSec, but graph moves on until leaving window.
passThruFrames = int(round(FPS * passThruSec))  # number of frames of the entire animation.
sampPerFrame = int(frameDurMs/1000*SR)  # frame size in samples
sampPerWindow = int(SR*WindowDurSec)  # window size in samples

x = np.linspace(0, DurSec, int(SR*DurSec))
y = Amp * np.sin(2 * np.pi * Freq * x)  # effective signal

# Add head and tail = 2 * windowSize
pad = np.zeros((sampPerWindow,), dtype=float)
Y = np.concatenate((pad, y, pad))


# Set up the figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, WindowDurSec), ylim=(-2*Amp, 2*Amp))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)  

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, WindowDurSec, sampPerWindow)
    start = i*sampPerFrame
    stop = start + sampPerWindow
    step = 1
    y = Y[start : stop : step]
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

# call the animator.  
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=passThruFrames, interval=frameDurMs, blit=True, repeat=False)

anim.save('sinewave_animation.mp4', fps=FPS, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: It's really hard to grasp what you think is going wrong here. But if the saved animation is fine, it might simply be the `interval` that's wrong. What exactly is the logic behind `frameDurMs = int(np.floor(1 / 30 * 1000))`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I updated my code above. Basically `frameDurMs = int(np.floor(1 / FPS * msPerSec)) ≈ secPerFrame * msPerSec = msPerFrame `, this should be the `interval` for the `FuncAnimation` call.

Comment: I think I can reproduce this. It's really weird, and sure needs some further investigation.